# Planejamento atualização de mensagens Android

Tags: android

Minha duvida é a seguinte.

Estou fazendo um aplicativo android e vou implementar a interface agora.

O aplicativo trabalha com um parse online onde pega os dados.
( penso em implementar como um service atualizando uma database )

Apos as atualizações que o service fizer na database como eu irei fazer o update na interface do usuario caso mensagens novas chegarem enquanto o usuario estiver na Activity ?

No caso pensei em fazer broadcast avisando de novas mensagens o aplicativo.

Alguem tem alguma outra sugestao de como implementar essa solucao ?

Answer (score 1):

O correto seria isso mesmo, poderia fazer um Service que fica buscando os dados no servidor e quando terminar a requisição envia um intent pra Activity informando que tem novos dados, assim a Activity recebe o intent e faz a ação necessária para atualizá-la.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de codigo organizado sobre algo desse tipo ?
Digo uma estrutura simples de classes

Answer (score 0):

Como você precisa que o serviço rode independente da activity você não pode criar ele acoplado (binded services) a activity.

Envie um broadcast do service e receba na activity dizendo que os dados foram atualizados.

A partir disso crie uma AsyncTask para interpretar os dados e atualizar na UI.